# printing html sections in separate pages not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

i have an html page whose values are displayed through php, the section starts like below:

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .section-to-print,
  .section-to-print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .section-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}

@media print {
  section {
    page-break-after: always !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="section-to-print" style="margin-left:15%">
  <div class="container">


    <div id="discs" class="container bootdey " style="padding-bottom:50px">
      <div class="row invoice row-printable ">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <!-- col-lg-12 start here -->
          <div class="panel panel-default plain border" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px" id="dash_0">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-body p30">
              <div class="row">

              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End .panel -->
          </div>
          <!-- col-lg-12 end here -->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</section>


<section class="section-to-print" style="margin-left:15%">
  <div class="container">


    <div id="discs" class="container bootdey " style="padding-bottom:50px">
      <div class="row invoice row-printable ">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <!-- col-lg-12 start here -->
          <div class="panel panel-default plain border" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px" id="dash_0">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-body p30">
              <div class="row">

              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End .panel -->
          </div>
          <!-- col-lg-12 end here -->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</section>


<section class="section-to-print" style="margin-left:15%">
  <div class="container">


    <div id="discs" class="container bootdey " style="padding-bottom:50px">
      <div class="row invoice row-printable ">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <!-- col-lg-12 start here -->
          <div class="panel panel-default plain border" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px" id="dash_0">
            <!-- Start .panel -->
            <div class="panel-body p30">
              <div class="row">

              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End .panel -->
          </div>
          <!-- col-lg-12 end here -->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

there are like 6 sections in the page, so when i click the print button am getting 2 sections in each page however i want one section only in a page, i did the following css:

this is still giving me 2 sections in a page, can anyone please tell me how to fix it, thanks

Comment: Please change your snippets to one [mcve] using RELEVANT RENDERED HTML and not server side code

Comment: Please change `<?php foreach($catil as $val){?>` to 6 sets of HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use **foreach** loop for sections

**example**

**foreach** for **array**

```
<?php
$colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

foreach ($colors as $value) {
  echo "$value <br>";
}
?>
```

Provide more information for better solution

Comment: i used foreachonly, in the answer i just did like that for an example

Comment: try to print it manually before loop and inside loop, or ur printing it twice . can you provide the php codes